# imagick transparentPaintImage not working

Tags: php, transparent, imagick

I have an image:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I am using this PHP/imagick code:

```
$BackgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 203)";
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage("xxxxxx");
$img->setImageFormat('png'); 
$img->transparentPaintImage($BackgroundColor,0,10,false);
$img->writeImage("xxxxxxx");
```

The resultant image does not change the yellow color to transparent.
i.e. The image remains yellow as per the image above.

Any suggestions would be appeciated.

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is slightly out of date. You need to calculate the fuzz percent against the system/library quantum range.

```php
$BackgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 203)";
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage("xxxxxx");
$img->setImageFormat('png'); 
$fuzz = Imagick::getQuantum() * 0.1; // 10%
$img->transparentPaintImage($BackgroundColor,0,$fuzz,false);
$img->writeImage("xxxxxxx");
```

[image]